# Which strategies,framework and applications tools can be implement to automatically monitor the health of the machine learning model?

Tags: machine-learning, modeling, monitoring

ML Models when deployed in the production environment, model degradation can arise where their output will change if the relationship between the incoming serving data and the predicted target drift apart.

Please can someone briefly elaborate what strategies,framework and applications tools can be implement to automatically monitor the health of the model and alert the Data Scientist of any decay in data quality, data drift and model quality.